# Does wood affect final gravity readings?

Tags: fermentation, specific-gravity

For beer aged either in oak barrels or on oak chips/cubes, does the contact with the oak noticeably affect final gravity, and if so, what is the direct cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really.  In a discussion of the subject on the AHA forum recently, it was brought up that using barrels will increase the "angel's share"...the beer that evaporates.  But it's such a small amount that it's negligible in terms of increasing the alcohol.  Using chips or cubes should have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: +1.  Alcohol evaporates more quickly than water.  Water won't evaporate through the barrel and leave a higher abv beer behind.

Answer (score 1):

Not as long as the wood isn't infested with Brettanomyces, anyway.

Comment: Even if it was that would be the brett not the wood causing a change in gravity.

Comment: True, but if you saw a significant change in gravity after racking to a barrel, that would be an indication that you have something in the barrel that will eat "unfermentable" sugars.  It addresses the "direct cause" portion of his question.